# Fermat's theorem for sums of two rational squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Guess a necessary and sufficient condition that $x^2+y^2=p$ to have rational solutions.

I know  the answers are when $p=2$ and $p \equiv 1\bmod 4$. I don't understand why these are good guesses. So I can't prove my guess..

Comment: Trying to solve the equation, say for $p$ up to $100$, would give some good empirical evidence for the conjecture.

Comment: So I wrote out the primes up to 100.. What do you mean ? How would I solve for $x^{2}$ + $y^{2}$= 2 and other primes for instance. I feel I would have to rewrite one term in the form of the other.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it was too hard to find a rational solution for $x^2+y^2=2\ldots$

Comment: So I find the rational solutions of all the primes.. How does this help me ?

Comment: That hasn't convinced you that $p=2$ and $p\equiv1$ (mod $4$) were good guesses? $\ddot\frown$

Comment: For 2 I got $x \congr y mod 2$

Comment: With the obvious exceptions, $p$ is odd. WLOG, require $x$ to be even and $y$ to be odd. Then $x^2$ is a multiple of 4 and $y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, which means that $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ as well. Therefore it's *necessary* for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Proving *sufficiency* is a little more difficult, but not by much.

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting hung up on the "guess" part? If you already *know* the answer, why don't you just pretend to guess it? Or maybe you can even make a wrong guess, such that $2p + 1$ also needs to be prime, or that $p$ has to be someone's lucky number.

Or you can pretend to gradually approach the answer. Can $p$ be negative? Well, no, because $x^2 \geq 0$ even if $x < 0$, likewise for $y^2$. So if $p = -2$ or $-5$, there is no solution, but with 2 or 5 instead, there are solutions, of which I'm sure you've already found the one for 2 if not also the one for 5. So $p$ has to be positive. It's necessary but not sufficient.

What about the parity of $p$? Since $p$ has to be positive, $p = 2$ is the only even possibility. The others have to be odd. You already know that the sum of two odd numbers is even, and you also know that an even number plus an odd number is odd.

But that doesn't explain why we can do $2^2 + 1^2 = 5$ but we can't find an integral solution for $p = 3$. So maybe it has something to do with congruence modulo 4. Indeed we see that if we require $x$ to be even and $y$ to be odd (no loss of generality there), we have $x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, even if $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $y \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Maybe this is enough for you to understand. If not, spend some time with ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Two_Squares_Theorem

Comment: ...and if you read the proof on ProofWiki and still think something is unclear, you can also ask for clarification there. The proofs at ProofWiki are meant to be lucid and intuitive.

Comment: @barto I did not mean to imply any slight to ProofWiki. I wholeheartedly refer people to that website, without reservation. I'd rather they go there than to that awful Wikipedia, which only confuses them more than they already were.

Comment: No offense taken. Wikipedia and ProofWiki, they both have their strengths, the one being extremely detailed, rigorous and understandable, the other giving an overview of interesting results and properties, whose proofs will one day appear at ProofWiki. My dream is to adopt ProofWiki as one of the Wikimedia projects, and connect the statements on Wikipedia to their proofs at Proofwiki.

Comment: You may want to support the ad: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27255/43288

Comment: There are ongoing discussions on proposing to have ProofWiki adopted by the Mediawiki Foundation. Any thoughts on it (or simply "yes please!") are welcome here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Talk:Main_Page#Adoption_by_the_Wikimedia_Foundation (but note these are just discussions and not yet an actual proposal)

Comment: @barto Thank you for letting me know about that.